# FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory. What Causes these Error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

Well, I'm using React. In my npm I'm getting below error sporadically. What cause these kinda Errors?? Is this because of too many npm Packages??

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 00007FF64180F04A v8::internal::GCIdleTimeHandler::GCIdleTimeHandler+5114
 2: 00007FF6417EA0C6 node::MakeCallback+4518
 3: 00007FF6417EAA30 node_module_register+2032
 4: 00007FF641A720EE v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+846
 5: 00007FF641A7201F v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+639
 6: 00007FF641F92BC4 v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+9556
 7: 00007FF641F910CB v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+2651
 8: 00007FF641B4CBE8 v8::internal::Factory::AllocateRawArray+56
 9: 00007FF641B4D562 v8::internal::Factory::NewFixedArrayWithFiller+66
10: 00007FF641BB5026 v8::internal::HashTable<v8::internal::NumberDictionary,v8::internal::NumberDictionaryShape>::EntryToIndex+72102
11: 00007FF641FB6B60 v8::internal::Bitmap::IsClean+29728
12: 000003380DBDC5C1
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Environment

```
OS : Windows 10 64 Bit.
Node : v10.15.3
npm : 6.4.1
React : 16.8.4
Webpack : 4.41.0
```

Comment: The internet (Github Issues, Stackoverflow) is full of this question. The bottom line is: It depends and provide a stack trace. I get this error every once in a while and ignore it. Upgrading to NodeJs 12 should, too.

Comment: *should help, too